# Microsoft ODBC driver can't find Oracle Instant Client

Tags: windows-7, database, odbc

I have an old 32-bit software program that connects to an Oracle database but only works with the Microsoft ODBC driver for Oracle.  It does not work with the more up-to-date native Oracle ODBC driver.

I have installed the Oracle Instant Client (32-bit and 64-bit versions on my 64-bit Win 7 PC), each into different ORACLE_HOME directories.

However when I try to connect via ODBC with Microsoft's driver, I get the error:

> The Oracle(tm) client and networking components were not found.   These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3 (or greater) client software installation.
>
> You will be unable to use this driver until these components have been installed.

I can connect to the database fine with Oracle's ODBC driver so the install seems fine, but alas this program will only work with Microsoft's ODBC driver.

Since the Microsoft ODBC driver is apparently unable to find the Oracle Instant Client install, how should I tell it where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is quite simple.  You have to set the `PATH` environment variable to point to the `ORACLE_HOME` that you want to use.

For me, I edited the `PATH` to add `;C:\oracle\instantclient32_12_1` on the end and it worked perfectly, no restart needed.

For clarification, the `C:\oracle\instantclient32_12_1` directory I specified contains files like `oci.dll` and `ociw32.dll` and belonged to the 32-bit Instant Client install.  I guess it doesn't matter for 64-bit, since there is no Microsoft ODBC 64-bit client.

Answer (score 1):

Technology used: Windows 7, UFT 32 bit, Data Source ODBC pointing out to 32 bit `C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe`, Oracle client with both versions installed 32 bit and 64 bit.

What worked for me:

1. Start -> search for “Edit the system environment variables”
2. System Variables -> Edit Path
3. Place the path for Oracle client 32 bit in front of the path for Oracle Client 64 bit. Ex:

   ```
   C:\APP\ORACLE\product\11.2.0\client_32\bin;C:\APP\ORACLE\product\11.2.0\client_64\bin
   ```